# how to use Oauth 2.0 with PKCE within Jmeter Taurus task in the pipeline to test APIs hosted on Azure App service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, jmeter-plugins, taurus

I am trying to use Jmeter plugin with Taurus tasks (Taurus Installer, Taurus Runner) in the Azure Release pipeline. I want to do perform testing of the APIs hosted on Azure App service. APIs are registered in Azure AD. Firstly, I need to use Oauth2.0 for Jmeter tasks to retrieve the access token so that it can perform the load testing of those APIs and along with data load testing. Currently, APIs are using Authorization Code Flow with PKCE so I am not sure how to retrieve the access token.

I am creating JMX script with Apache Jmeter tool and using that JMX script in the Azure Release pipeline. But I need to use Oauth 2.0 in the pipeline so that performance testing can be performed.

I can do the above with postman but not sure about Jmeter.

Any suggestion.
Thank you

Comment: Hi @ANIL have you got this working?

Answer (score 0):

If you can "do the above with postman" you should be able to do this with JMeter, the easiest way of bypassing the OAuth challenge is to

1. [Record the requests originating from Postman using JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling)
2. And perform the [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of the dynamic parameters according to [RFC 7636](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636)

Comment: I do not want to bypass the OAuth